# Reporting on release changes when using JIRA, Ivy and SVN

Tags: java, svn, jira, ivy

Our team has a number of independant services, and (possibly nested) dependant versioned libraries - currently managed in Ivy. Whenever a dependant library is updated, all libraries and services dependant on this need to be re-released.

Therefore the author of a change can carry other people's changes out to Production. We want to generate reports and track changes to dependancies between releases but there doesn't seem to be an easy way of doing this without a significant effort.

We also want to generate a JIRA list of all changes not only in the main project but in dependancies that we own. This is an extension of the problem above.

Otherwise we simply don't know what we are releasing - any ideas?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just been working on the same thing for JIRA, Maven release plugins and Mercurial. The good news for you is that the JIRA Mercurial plugin is based on the JIRA Subversion plugin, so  porting the work to the Subversion plugin would not be a crazy amount of work.

Can you give some more detail about how the Ivy release process uses dependencies? The idea of pulling in changes you weren't expecting sounds a bit risky!

~Matt

Comment: Thanks. 
How do you manage 'internal' dependancies in your team? 
Do you report on internal changes that you are pulling in through Maven?